# Rest Assured - Using ResponseSpecBuilder Results in Empty Extracted Response

Tags: rest, response, extract, builder, rest-assured

IF I remove

> .spec(responseSpec)

from my call, the response prints fine at "FOO". If I include the builder, the response prints an empty string (even though the test is passing). Anyone know why, or how to fix this? I would like to use the builder and print the response of the passing test.

```
public void getCirclesId()
    {
        String endpoint = "getCirclesId";
        String url = baseUrl + resourcePath + "/" + circleId;
        RequestSpecification given = given().header("Authorization", RestTest.BEARER_TOKEN);

        ResponseSpecBuilder specBuilder = new ResponseSpecBuilder();
        specBuilder.expectBody("features.priceMonth", is("5.00"));
        specBuilder.expectBody("features.priceYear", is("50.00"));
        Response response = JsonTest.executeRequestWithSpec(given, url, resource, endpoint, JsonTest.HttpType.GET, specBuilder);
    }
```

...

```
public static Response executeRequestWithSpec(RequestSpecification given, String url, String resource, String endpoint, HttpType type, ResponseSpecBuilder builder)
    {
        Response response = null;
        try {
            switch (type) {
                case GET:
                    response = executeGetRequestWithSpec(given, url, builder);
                    break;
                case POST:
                    response = executePostRequestWithSpec(given, url, builder);
                    break;
                case PUT:
                    response = executePutRequestWithSpec(given, url, builder);
                    break;
                case DELETE:
                    response = executeDeleteRequestWithSpec(given, url, builder);
                    break;
            }

            System.out.println(resource + " - " + endpoint + ": " + response.print());
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            RestTest.failCount++;
            System.err.println(resource + " - " + endpoint + " Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private static Response executeGetRequestWithSpec(RequestSpecification given, String url, ResponseSpecBuilder builder)
    {
        ResponseSpecification responseSpec = builder.build();
        Response response = given.when().get(url + ".json").then().assertThat().statusCode(200).spec(responseSpec).extract().response();
        System.out.println("FOOOO" + response.print());
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of REST Assured (currently 2.3.0)? Otherwise I suggest you to upgrade to this version. There was some problems with response specifications in 2.0.